# Understanding what is PROP set and things within.

Tags: logic

I'm studying **Logic and Structure** by **Van Dalen** and I came across this

> *The set PROP of propositions is the smallest set $X$ with the properties*
>
> 1. $ p_i \in X (i \in N),~ \bot \in X,$
> 2. $\varphi, \psi \in X \implies \left( \varphi \land \psi \right), \left(\varphi \lor \psi \right), \left(\varphi \implies \psi \right), \left( \varphi \iff \psi \right) \in X$.
> 3. $\varphi \in X \implies \left( \neg \varphi \right) \in X$

Now, there are few things that I don't understand about it, first of all it is very very unintuitive, can you please explain me the intuition of PROP set?

In the previous section of the book **Van Dalen** said that we would denote propositions by letters $p_0, p_1, p_2...$ and he  follows it in the first property but why he no longer use it from the second properties onwards, why he moved to greek letters?

I'm finding it hard to digest why a contradiction, that is $\bot$ needs to be an element of PROP set.

Please help me to understand these things in an untechnical way.

Comment: $\text {PROP}$ is the set of **all** syntactically correct formulas (aka: well-formed) of propositional logic.

Comment: The language is made from propositional letters: $p_0, p_1, \ldots$ and $\bot$: the *atoms* (step 1 above) building "complex" formulas using *connectives* : $\lnot, \to$ etc. (step 2 and 3).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Does $\bot$ refers to a proposition which is always false?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sir I’m sorry but your first comment is not understandable by me, I don’t know why but I’m finding it very hard to associate “set of syntactical correct formulas” with those three properties. What is formula after all in the context of propositions?

Comment: The formulas of prop calculus are "generated" according to the rules above: start with $\bot$, or one of $p_0,p_1,\ldots$ or any combination of them with connectives; this is step 1. Then use all formulas produced in step 1 and combine them with connectives to generate new formulas; this is step 2. And repeat the procedure.

Comment: Simple exercise with paper and pencil: start from $\bot, p_0,p_1$ and write the formulas that you can generate according to the rules above.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What is intended by the word “formula” here?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What is a formula? Are you asking me to write something like this $$ (p_0 \lor p_1) \land \bot \implies \bot$$ ?

Comment: Exactly; see van Dalen page 8.

Comment: For Greeks letters, see bottom page 7.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Why $\neg \neg \bot$ is not a valid syntax?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104818/discussion-between-adesh-mishra-and-mauro-allegranza).

Comment: Because the rules for negation says: $(\lnot (\lnot \bot))$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA WOW! But where is this rule written in those three properties?

Comment: It is bullett 3. By 1 $\bot \in PROP$. By 2 $(\lnot \bot) \in PROP$. By 2 again $(\lnot (\lnot \bot)) \in PROP$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you so much.